# Adjust user to point in slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, slider

I try to build sliders with different categories that each user has his point.
The informant comes from the json server

What I need I do not succeed in having the customer choose a user that is numbered and the dot will be colored in the slider How do I do that?

In addition he has the option to delete and return the point.
I was able to delete the points by deleting them in the object. But I could not return, is there a possibility to return?

**Broker.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Combo from '../components/Combo/Combo';
import Sliders from '../components/Sliders/Sliders';

const GetUsersDataFromManipulation = (users, field) => {

    const state = users.reduce((store, user) => {

        const userId = user.user
        const currentManipulationUserData = user.profileManipulation[field]

        if (currentManipulationUserData.length === 0) {

            return store
        }

        store[userId] = currentManipulationUserData[0].bid

        return store;

    }, {})

    return state;

};



function Broker({ manipulations }) {
    const users = manipulations[2].users
    const [hiddenUser, setHiddenUser] = useState(() => {

        const visible = {};
        for (let user of users) {
            visible[user.user] = true;
        }
        return visible;

    })
    const GetUsersBid = (profileManipulation) => {
        const data = GetUsersDataFromManipulation(users, `${profileManipulation}`); if (!Object.keys(data).length) {
            return null
        }
        return data;
    };

    const gender = GetUsersBid('gender');
    const age = GetUsersBid('age');
    const marital = GetUsersBid('marital');
    const children = GetUsersBid('children');
    const education = GetUsersBid('education');
    const interests = GetUsersBid('interests');
    const dynamicInterests = GetUsersBid('dynamicInterests');



    const showUser = (user_id) => {
        const new_hidden = { ...hiddenUser }
        new_hidden[user_id] = true;

        setHiddenUser(new_hidden);
    }

    const hideUser = (user_id) => {
        const new_hidden = { ...hiddenUser }
        console.log(user_id)
        new_hidden[user_id] = false;
        setHiddenUser(new_hidden);
    }

    const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState([
        { name: 'gender', bids: gender },
        { name: 'age', bids: age },
        { name: 'marital', bids: marital },
        { name: 'children', bids: children },
        { name: 'education', bids: education },
        { name: 'interests', bids: interests },
        { name: 'dynamicInterests ', bids: dynamicInterests },

    ]);



    useEffect(() => {

        const curret_User_Info = [...userInformation]


        for (let user of Object.keys(hiddenUser)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < curret_User_Info.length; i++) {
                if (curret_User_Info[i].bids !== null) {
                    if (hiddenUser[user] === false) {

                        delete curret_User_Info[i].bids[user]

                    }
                    else {
//What am I returning here? So that the bids will return?
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        setUserInformation(curret_User_Info)


    }, [hiddenUser])




    return (
        <div>
            <div className="button" >
                {userInformation && <Combo users={users} showUser={showUser} hideUser={hideUser} userInformation={userInformation} />}

            </div>
            <div className='slid'>
                {userInformation.map(sliderDetails => {


                    return (
                        <div className={sliderDetails.name} key={sliderDetails.name} >

                            {sliderDetails.bids && (<Sliders className="sliders" hiddenUserChange={hiddenUser} name={sliderDetails.name} userBids={sliderDetails.bids} setUserInformation={setUserInformation} userInformation={userInformation} />)}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Broker;
```

**ComboBox.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import ComboBox from 'react-responsive-combo-box';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import 'react-responsive-combo-box/dist/index.css';
import "./style.css"


function Combo({ users, showUser, hideUser, userInformation }) {

    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState();
    const [choosing, setChoosing] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {


    }, [users])

    const onShow = () => {
        showUser(users[selectedOption - 1].user)

    }

    const onHide = () => {
        hideUser(users[selectedOption - 1].user)
    }
    const colorChange = (numOption) => {
        const id = users[numOption - 1].user

    }


    return (
        <div className="combo_box">
            <ComboBox
                onSelect={(option) => { setSelectedOption(option); colorChange(option) }}
                options={[...Array.from({ length: users.length }, (_, i) => i + 1)]}
            />

            <div className='button' >
                <Button style={{ "marginRight": 20 }} variant="contained" onClick={onShow}>Show</Button>
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={onHide}>Hide</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Combo;
```

**Sliders.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import "./style.css"
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';

const Sliders = ({ hiddenUserChange, name, userBids, setUserInformation, userInformation }) => {
    
    
    
    const [bids, setBids] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {


        setBids(Object.values(userBids))


    }, [hiddenUserChange, userBids])


    const updateFieldChanged = (newValue, e) => {//OnChanged Slider

        setUserInformation(state => {
            return state.map(manipulation => {

                if (manipulation.name === name) {
                    Object.entries(manipulation.bids).forEach(([userId, bidValue], index) => {
                        manipulation.bids[userId] = newValue[index]
                        console.log(manipulation.bids[userId])
                    })
                }

                return manipulation
            })

        });

    }

    const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
        setBids(event)

    };


    return (
        <>

            <h1 className='headers'>{name}</h1>

            {
                <Slider
                    style={{ "marginRight": "20rem", "width": "30rem", "left": "20%" }}
                    range={true}
                    trackStyle={[{ backgroundColor: '#3f51b5' }]}
                    max={100}
                    RcSlider={true}
                    railStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3f51b5' }}
                    activeDotStyle={{ left: 'unset' }}
                    ariaLabelForHandle={Object.keys(hiddenUserChange)}
                    tabIndex={(Object.keys(userBids))}
                    ariaLabelledByForHandle={bids}
                    value={(bids)}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onAfterChange={updateFieldChanged}
                    tipProps
                    tipFormatter

                />

            }
        </>
    )
}

export default Sliders
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQCHu.png)

Thank you all!

Comment: Not able to understand your 2nd question related to return while deleting, are you referring deleing to deleting a user by customer and also can you explain what does return here means?

Comment: I succeeded with the second problem ..

All I have left to do is paint the dots